# Synchronizing network file system

Tags: networking, file-synchronization

I have a colocated server with lots of space and a hardware RAID setup, and a small home server that is optimized to be silent.

I'd like to set up a networked file system where all files are ultimately stored on the colo server, and the home server acts as a cache for fast access, re-exporting the tree as CIFS shares.

I'm looking into the [Andrew File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_File_System), which is horribly complex to set up, and am wondering if there is a simpler alternative.